# jQuery mobile css and js equvalent code for desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I wanted to have a collapsible list in my html. Here is the [end result in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lodt0bdj/1/) using jquery mobile, however, I cannot use jquery mobile since I am using jquery in my code already and it seems to mess with my desktop ui. Are there equivalent code I can reference to create the same result?

Relevant code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h2>My Phonebook</h2>
<div data-role="collapsible">
<h4>A</h4>
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
<h4>B</h4>
<ul data-role="listview">
   <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
<h4>C</h4>
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cameron</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chloe</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having using both jQueryMobile and jQuery? Since jQueryMobile depends on jQuery there should be no conflicts. I have used them in tandem many times.

Comment: My ui mess up when I include `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js`. Maybe it have known compatibility issue with bootstrap, I use a combination of jquery mobile and bootstrap in my website

Comment: Oh yes, I agree it doesn't work well with bootstrap. I tried adding jQueryMobile to get certain functionality in a bootstrap site. They don't work well together.

Comment: ah, thanks for letting me know that. Did you end up writing your own solution for your site?

Comment: Yes and we just don't use collapsible. Instead we opted for bootstrap button dropdowns.